# How to skip a part of the file then read a line?

Tags: java, file, split, bufferedreader

I have a code that reads a file using buffered reader and split, said file was created via a method that automatically adds 4KB of empty space at the beginning of the file, this results in when I read the following happens:

First the Code:

```
BufferedReader metaRead = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(metaFile));
String metaLine = "";
String [] metaData = new String [100000];

        while ((metaLine = metaRead.readLine()) != null){
            metaData = metaLine.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < metaData.length; i++){
                System.out.println(metaData[i]);
        }
        }
```

This is the result, keep in mind this file already exists and contains the values:

```
    //4096 spaces then the first actual word in the document which is --> testTable2
Name
java.lang.String
true
No Reference
```

Is there a way to skip the first 4096 spaces, and get straight to the actual value within the file so I can get the result regularly? Because I'll be using the metaData array later in other operations, and I'm pretty sure the spaces will mess up the number of slots within the array. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered, err, `BufferedReader.skip()`?

Comment: And why not fix the file creation to get rid of the pointless 4K spaces? Instead of building co-operating bugs?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, the auto-completion should help.

```
metaRead.skip(4096);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

Comment: I may have misread your question. You want to skip 4096 spaces, and not bytes?

Comment: Same thing, and `Reader.skip()` skips characters.

Comment: I meant that if he had a bunch of characters, some of which were letters, numbers, etc. and he wanted to skip 4096 spaces, then this wouldn't work.

But I supposed the number 4096 is a pretty big clue.

Answer (score 0):

You could (as mentioned) simply do:

`metaRead.skip(4096);`

If the whitespace always occupies that many characters, or you could just avoid lines which are empty

```
while ((metaLine = metaRead.readLine()) != null){
    if(metaLine.trim().length() > 0){
        metaData = metaLine.split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < metaData.length; i++){
            System.out.println(metaData[i]);
        }
    }
}
```